# Save datas from multiple checkbox in a database

Tags: php, arrays, database, post, checkbox

2 Questions about saving data from multiple checkbox (I have few of them in my form) in a database with PDO (PHP). I just show the relevant parts of the code to make it more simple for everyone.

A) The code I wrote works (still saving all data correctly) but it gives me still a failure message, which you can see below. Why, or what can I do better?

B) It saves the checked checkboxes as an array in the database. Later on I want to change data by getting the data from the database back into my original form - will it make problems, if its saved like an array? If yes, what would you recommend to do then better.

> Warning: implode ( ) : Invalid arguments passed on line ...  for

```
$p2 = implode(',',$product_2);
$p3 = implode(',',$product_3);
```

---

```
$p1 = implode(',',$product_1);  which I defined first seems to be fine
```

---

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['send']))
    {   
        require("php/tconnect.php");    

        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $p1 = implode(',',$product_1);
        $p2 = implode(',',$product_2);
        $p3 = implode(',',$product_3);  

        $sql = "INSERT INTO database (id, name, date) VALUES (:id, :name, :date, '$p1', '$p2', '$p3')";
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
        $stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
        $stmt->bindValue(':date', $date);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo "Datas saved";             
    }
?>
```

---

HTML

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="product_1[]" value="apple" id="product_1_apple">
    Apple 
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="product_1[]" value="Banana" id="product_1_banana">
    Banana
</label>
```

and the next tables looks similar

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="product_2[]" value="water" id="product_2_water">
    Water 
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="product_2[]" value="juice" id="product_2_juice">
    Juice 
</label>
```

Comment: Although a warning is not an error, almost always it means that there is something that is not right in your code, probably one of your products is not being saved. What is code in the line you get the warning (or the warnings)?

Comment: Thank you, thats right, its for these lines: $p2 = implode(',',$product_2); and 
$p3 = implode(',',$product_3);  - for the first time I used   $p1 = implode(',',$product_1);  I don't get a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$product_1`, `$product_2` and `$product_3` seems to be related with the input arrays from the HTML I suppose that you have in another part of the code something like this:

```
$product_1 = $_POST['product_1'];
$product_2 = $_POST['product_2'];
$product_3 = $_POST['product_3'];
```

Now, the problem is that those variables are related to an array of checkboxes, but when no checkbox is selected in the page for a group, instead of getting an empty array for that group *the array is not added to $_POST* (you can see it using `var_dump($_POST)`).

I suspect that in your tests you were only marking checkboxes for product_1, so you get an array for that product but no for the other ones. To prevent the error you can fill each of the products variables using something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['product_1']))  // if the array is defined in $_POST
    $product_1 = $_POST['product_1'];  // fill with the array from the form
else $product_1 = array();  // fill with empty array, you get the empty string with implode()

// repeat for product_2 and product_3
```

Also, you are mixing prepared statements, which are good, with inserting the values directly in the query string, which is bad because it can lead to [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp), you should use `bindValue()` for all the values of the table:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO database (id, name, date) VALUES (:id, :name, :date, :p1, :p2, :p3)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindValue(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindValue(':date', $date);
$stmt->bindValue(':p1', $p1);
$stmt->bindValue(':p2', $p2);
$stmt->bindValue(':p3', $p3);
```

Comment: Now just the last part of the question.
Is it possible to get the data (for example 3 different names (like checked checkboxes) are saved in one row of my database) back in my form, so all checkboxes are checked correctly. If yes, which commend do I use. If no, how can I make it work?

Comment: It's possible but it takes a bit of work, first you use the [`explode()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to convert the values you get from the database back to an array, and then based on the values of the array you add the [`checked` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_input_checked.asp) to the appropriate input tag with PHP, something like: `<input type="checkbox" name="product_1[]" value="apple" <?php if(in_array("apple", $exploded_array)) echo "checked"?>>` (see ([`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function docs).

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, I wanted to try first before answer. That works perfectly! Thank you so much Alberto!